# How to make symbol decrease at the ends in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

[image: Ocad-Style symbol decrease]

Is there a way to make symbol size decrease/increase at the ends of line like in OCAD?

In the first line the brown dot is decreased near to the end of line.
In the second line the symbol is brown rectangle. It is spaced very tightly and decreased at the end, producing effect of thinned line.

Answer (score 4):

**1. Points**

Assuming this is a point layer containing features which are ordered accordingly, you could create a field containing decreasing values. Then use this field for the `Size` setting in the layer's **Style Properties**.

Depending on how your layer is structured (i.e. if it contains several groups of points), you may need to select your points carefully and then either manually enter a size in the attribute field or use an expression.

---

**2. Lines**

Assuming this is a line layer, you could use the **Arrow** symbol layer type and set it so that the `Head length` and `Head thickness` have a value of 0. And then set the `Arrow width at start` and `Arrow width` settings to play with the size:

[image: Line style settings]

This could create a line of varying size:

[image: Result]

Comment: The first example is actually a line feature. May be there is some sort of expresiiaon to get dhe diatance from the end of line feature and calculate according thikness?

Answer (score 2):

From QGIS 3.20 the interpolated line symbol layer type is available, which results in the rendering of a color and/or width varying line. See [visual changelog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-interpolated-line-symbol-layer-type-for-vector-layers).

Comment: Yeah! Seen it in the recent newsletter