# Variable-width (tapered) line styling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

I am looking for a way to style a line. I would like to change the line width between two vertexes, lets say from 2 to 4px. Is this possible to do in some way?

I was thinking about converting the lines to polygons but haven’t figured out any workflow that would work.

This is to make lines of different classes and widths melt together more beautifully.

Comment: Do u mean u want to only affect a **segment** of the line (and not all the line) ?

Comment: I don’t know at the moment but perhaps just the last bit. Consider a road network where a major road turns into a smaller. I would like the transition to be smoother than the intersection between two different line widths.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to make symbol decrease at the ends in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262028/how-to-make-symbol-decrease-at-the-ends-in-qgis)

Comment: If you figure out a way to get the look you want with polygons, you can use the geometry generator to display it. That'll save you from needing to convert the lines to a new polygon layer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make symbol decrease at the ends in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262028/how-to-make-symbol-decrease-at-the-ends-in-qgis)